# Firebase/Swift - Outputting data from Firebase gone wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue outputting data from Firbase properly. I have spent many hours and tried lots of different ways of doing this, creating different data structures etc but I would alway get a crash or nil output. My current code is working and outputting data from firebase into a table view, however the arrays are misaligned and the fields in one array for a particular user do not relate to the other, which is not correct..

I imagine there is a better way of doing this so any help or a point in the right direction with this would be much appreciated. Also please go easy on me, i'm knew to this :)

This is my firebase structure:

[image]

This is my Rentals model:

```
struct RentalObjects {

    var title: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var rentalType: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var dateAval: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var location: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var price: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var bond: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var pets: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
    var descripton: [String : AnyObject] = [:]

}
```

This is my code for the VC outputting to the table view :

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase


class RentalTableViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var rentalImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rentalTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rentalPrice: UILabel!


    var rentalsObject = RentalObjects()
    var databaseRef:DatabaseReference?
    var handle: DatabaseHandle?

    var arrayOfTitles = [String?]()
    var arrayOfBond = [String?]()



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rentalsObject.title.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        for (_, value) in rentalsObject.title {
            arrayOfTitles.append(value as? String)

        }

        for (_, value) in rentalsObject.bond {

            arrayOfBond.append(value as? String)

        }


        cell.textLabel?.text = ("Title: \(String(describing: arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row]!)), Bond: \(String(describing: arrayOfBond[indexPath.row]!))")



        return cell
    }


    @IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


        databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rentals")
        databaseRef?.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for rentals in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {





        switch rentals.key {

                case "title" :
                    let titleObj = rentals.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                    self.rentalsObject.title = titleObj

                case "rentalType":
                    let rentalTypeObj = rentals.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.rentalType = rentalTypeObj

                case "dateAval":
                    let dateAvalObj = rentals.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.dateAval = dateAvalObj
                case "location":
                    let locationObj = rentals.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.location = locationObj

                case "price" :
                    let priceObj = rentals.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.price = priceObj

                case "bond" :
                    let bondObj = rentals.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.bond = bondObj

                case "pets" :
                    let petsObj = rentals.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.pets = petsObj

                case "description":
                    let desObj = rentals.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    self.rentalsObject.descripton = desObj

                default:
                    break

                }

            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .childAdded instead .value. ChildAdded get each object, while Value get all objects. You should remove for-loops from 'cellForRowAr' method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

       cell.textLabel?.text = ("Title: \(String(describing: arrayOfTitles[indexPath.row]!)), Bond: \(String(describing: arrayOfBond[indexPath.row]!))")

       return cell
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rentals")
   databaseRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

       if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

          switch snapshot.key {

             case "title" :
             _ = dictionary.map{self.arrayOfTitles.append($0.value as? String)}
             case "rentalType":

             case "dateAval":

             case "location":

             case "price" :

             case "bond" :
             _ = dictionary.map{self.arrayOfBond.append($0.value as? String)}
             case "pets" :

             case "description":

             default:
                break
           }
        }
     })
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Hi a.afanasiev, ive managed to get this working now but I am having the same issue as before with my previous code. The output from the arrays appear to be doing something strange which causes them to become misaligned with each other. I have posted my code below in another question for easier readability.

Comment: Hi a.afanasiev, ive managed to get this working now but I am having the same issue as before with my previous code. The output from the arrays appear to be doing something strange which causes them to become misaligned with each other. if I print the arrays from within the ViewDidLoad func they appear correct - however if I output them to the label or print from within the cellForRowAt function the arrays appear duplicated. Any ideas as to why that would happen?

Comment: what do you return on 'numberOfRowsInSection' method? rentalsObject.title.count or arrayOfTitles.count?

Comment: I am returning the arrayOfTitles.count as if I return the rentals.Object.title.count then the CellForRowAt func doesn't seem to get called at all and I get nothing in the table view?